# Error : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'

Tags: python

unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'

I am getting this message while I’m trying to run this code:

```
def old_macdonald(name):

    first_letter = name[0]
    inbetween = name[1:3]
    fourth_letter = name [3]
    rest = name[4:]

    return first_letter.upper+ inbetween+ fourt_letter.upper+ rest
```

Comment: You need to call the method `first_letter.upper()`

Answer (score 1):

`string.upper()` is a function, so you need to use the parenthesis:

```
return first_letter.upper()+ inbetween+ fourt_letter.upper()+ rest
```